# Want a single json array object from another multiple array objects for API consume using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, express, object

**1. I have below json data coming from another API. It displays country and Flag in separate Array objects**

```
{
"data": [
            {
                "service": "Tourist Visa",
                "service_id": 2,
                "country_id": 2,
                "country_name": "Australia",
                "country_flag": "https://getset-visa.s3.amazonaws.com/images/flag/australia-flag.JPG"
            },
            {
                "service": "Tourist Visa",
                "service_id": 2,
                "country_id": 1,
                "country_name": "India",
                "country_flag": "https://getset-visa.s3.amazonaws.com/images/countries/Indian-Flag.png"
            },
            {
                "service": "Visa Services",
                "service_id": 3,
                "country_id": 1,
                "country_name": "India",
                "country_flag": "https://getset-visa.s3.amazonaws.com/images/countries/Indian-Flag.png"
            }
        ]
}
```

**2. I want to convert it to like below, Using JavaScript for consuming in API. Like One country data in one array and another country data in separate array object along with country, flag and a services array**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "countryName": "Australia",
      "countryFlag": "https://getset-visa.s3.amazonaws.com/images/flag/australia-flag.JPG",
      "services": [
        {
          "serviceName": "Tourist Visa"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "countryName": "India",
      "countryFlag": "https://getset-visa.s3.amazonaws.com/images/countries/Indian-Flag.png",
      "services": [
        {
          "serviceName": "Visa Services"
        },
        {
          "serviceName": "Tourist Visa"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can use `Array#reduce` and `Map`.

```js
const response = {
  data: [
    {
      service: "Tourist Visa",
      service_id: 2,
      country_id: 2,
      country_name: "Australia",
      country_flag:
        "https://getset-visa.s3.amazonaws.com/images/flag/australia-flag.JPG",
    },
    {
      service: "Tourist Visa",
      service_id: 2,
      country_id: 1,
      country_name: "India",
      country_flag:
        "https://getset-visa.s3.amazonaws.com/images/countries/Indian-Flag.png",
    },
    {
      service: "Visa Services",
      service_id: 3,
      country_id: 1,
      country_name: "India",
      country_flag:
        "https://getset-visa.s3.amazonaws.com/images/countries/Indian-Flag.png",
    },
  ],
};

const output = Array.from(response.data.reduce(
  (m, {country_id: id, country_name: countryName, country_flag: countryFlag, service: serviceName}) => (
    m.has(id)
      ? m.get(id).services.push({ serviceName })
      : m.set(id, { countryName, countryFlag, services: [{ serviceName }] }),
    m
  ),
  new Map()
).values());

console.log({data: output});
```

Comment: @VijayBhatia Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: @georg Oh my bad! Thanks for pointing out. I will update my answer.

Comment: Som. I want some different output

Comment: @VijayBhatia I've updated my answer, please take a look, is this what you want?

Comment: Yeah, @SomShekharMukherjee. its perfect. This is what i was looking for. Thanks a lot.